# Automate graph generation from dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe, automation, seaborn, graphing

I need to automatically generate approximately 320 individual graphs. I can successfully plot 5-18 graphs for one person. There are approx 7500+ rows of total data. Each row represents a reversal position.

I need to pull and then plot by: 
1. participant (19 participants), 
2. wavelength (number of wavelengths varies by person, some have as few as 4, others as many as 20), 
3. increment or decrement (positive or negative conditions), and 
4. experiment number (1-4).

Below is code that works to show 5 graphs for one participant, one graph per 5 wavelengths, using seaborn. I have approximately 20 participants (listed in the data as Person by initials). I want to write a script that will essentially make several graphs for each person and condition.

I can query or sort the data by 1. experiment, 2. person, 3. condition (threshold pos or neg numbers) and 4. wavelength. I have not figured out how to call or store that data for graphing.

For example, this code works if I want to manually fill in each person's initials, wavelength, Inc/Dec(threshold) and every experiment number:

```
#select the desired items out of the dataframe
df[(df.Per == 'AEM') & (df.WL == 488) & (df.IncDec == 1) & (df.ExpNum == 4)]
```

Or this works to sort, but I don't know how to use it to generate each person's graphs.

```
# sort the data in the dataframe
df.sort_values(['ExpNum', 'IncDec', 'Per', 'WL'], ascending=[True, True, True, True], inplace=True)
```

I also tried making dictionaries for each of the fields I would need to call, but did not know how to use this in a loop to call each item, either. This is one example, showing unique instances of the wavelength values in my dataframe:

```
>>> dfsWL_key_names
dict_keys([428, 440, 452, 464, 476, 488, 500, 512, 524, 536, 548, 560, 572, 584, 596, 608, 620, 632, 644, 656, 668, 680])
```

Each graph might need to show a different number of data points, for example, 1-?? reversals. Most cases the reversal number is 12 (12 points to graph) but in some, there are fewer reversal positions to graph the maximum is 15 positive and negative reversal positions to graph for one person at one wavelength. There are not the same number of points to plot for each person at every wavelength in every condition.

The logic would be:
for each unique person in the dataframe,
for each experiment for that person, 
for each wavelength, take each of their data points and plot them with reversal number on the x-axis and reversal position on the y-axis.

Not sure how to constuct several nested loops that would allow me to grab each unique person's records, and then the unique wavelengths, and then separate out increments vs. decrements (stored as 0 and 1) and then plot that data. Then go back into a loop and repeat that for each wavelength for that person, repeat for each experiment (4x), then repeat the same steps for each other participant.

The code below that works for one participant requires me to only import their data into a dataframe without any other participants, experiments, etc. Example of the reduced data, here. The actual data set is much larger and has additional columns with everyone's data.

```
   RevNum   WL     RevPos
0       1  440  20.934543
1       2  440  26.934543
2       3  440  20.354543
3       4  440  26.354543
4       5  440  24.714543


           RevNum          WL      RevPos
count  120.000000  120.000000  120.000000
mean     6.500000  464.000000    7.798258
std      3.466527   17.041718   27.414977
min      1.000000  440.000000  -33.628026
25%      3.750000  452.000000  -19.736296
50%      6.500000  464.000000    9.004679
75%      9.250000  476.000000   31.219357
max     12.000000  488.000000   50.000000

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 120 entries, 0 to 119
Data columns (total 3 columns):
RevNum    120 non-null int64
WL        120 non-null int64
RevPos    120 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2)
memory usage: 2.9 KB
```

The actual data set I need to use is larger, example data:

```
   OriginalDataID Person       ...       ExpNumber  LightIntensity
0            1611    JMA       ...               1              60
1            1618    JMA       ...               1              60
2            1621    JMA       ...               1              60
3            1666    JMA       ...               1              60
4            1669    JMA       ...               1              60

[5 rows x 9 columns]

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 7135 entries, 0 to 7134
Data columns (total 9 columns):
OriginalDataID    7135 non-null int64
Person            7135 non-null object
Date              7135 non-null object
Threshold0Inc     7135 non-null int64
RevNum            7135 non-null int64
Wavelength        7135 non-null int64
RevPos            7135 non-null float64
ExpNumber         7135 non-null int64
LightIntensity    7135 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(6), object(2)
memory usage: 501.8+ KB
```

This works with the subset of data for 1 person, 1 experiment, to generate a separate graph for each of the 5 wavelengths:

```
#import modules aka packages
import pandas as pd # Pandas (advanced data manipulation)
import numpy as np # Numpy (data import, manipulation, export)
import seaborn as sns # Seaborn visualization library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # Matplotlib (create trends)

# import data in csv file
# Old Longer Names
# df = pd.read_csv('rev_data1.csv', sep=',', delimiter=None, header='infer', names=['OriginalDataID', 'Person', 'Date', 'Threshold0Inc', 'RevNum', 'Wavelength', 'RevPos', 'ExpNumber', 'LightIntensity'], 
df = pd.read_csv('rev_data10.csv', sep=',', delimiter=None, header='infer', names=['RevNum', 'WL', 'RevPos'], 
index_col=None, usecols=None, squeeze=False, prefix=None, mangle_dupe_cols=True, dtype=None, engine='python', 
converters=None, true_values=None, false_values=None, skipinitialspace=False, skiprows=1, 
nrows=None, na_values=None, keep_default_na=True, na_filter=True, verbose=False, skip_blank_lines=True, 
parse_dates=False,infer_datetime_format=True, keep_date_col=False, date_parser=None, dayfirst=False, 
iterator=False, chunksize=None, compression='infer', thousands=None, decimal=b'.', lineterminator=None, 
quotechar='"', quoting=0, escapechar=None, comment=None, encoding=None, dialect=None, tupleize_cols=None, 
error_bad_lines=True, warn_bad_lines=True, skipfooter=0, doublequote=True, delim_whitespace=False, 
low_memory=True, memory_map=False, float_precision=None)

####
sns.set(style="ticks")

# Create a dataset 1
pos = df.RevPos
step = df.RevNum
walk = df.WL

# Initialize a grid of plots with an Axes for staircases for each wavelength
grid = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="WL", hue="WL", col_wrap=5, size=1.5)

# Draw a horizontal line at backgound luminance of 0
grid.map(plt.axhline, y=0, ls=":", c=".5")

# Draw a horizontal line showing min max constraints of staircase
grid.map(plt.axhline, y=-50, ls=":", c=".5")
grid.map(plt.axhline, y=50, ls=":", c=".5")

# Draw a line plot to show reversals of staircase
grid.map(plt.plot, "RevNum", "RevPos", marker="o", ms=4)

# Adjust the tick positions and labels
grid.set(xticks=np.arange(13), yticks=[-60, -40, -20, 0, 20, 40, 60],
    xlim=(-.5, 12.5), ylim=(-65, 65))

# Adjust the arrangement of the plots
grid.fig.tight_layout(w_pad=1)

plt.show()
```

Example graph: One person's data, 1 experiment, 5 wavelengths w/both neg and pos data.

[image: Example graph: One person's data, 1 experiment, 5 wavelengths w/both neg and pos data]

Comment: I've been reading this and trying figure out what exactly your question is, to no avail. Maybe you could be more specific about where you're stuck? Your post is pretty long, is there any way you can reduce it/break it up into several questions?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will see how I can break it up into several questions. I'm new to programming in python. I want to be able to automate making several hundred graphs based on unique values in my data frame. I do not know how to use various queries to create several sub-sets of data based on 1. experiment, 2. person, 3. condition (threshold pos or neg numbers) and 4. wavelength

Comment: Currently, if I take each person's experiment and put it into a separate .csv file, then I can run each of those through my code. I have 20+ participants, and I was hoping to write a script that can go through one large .csv file with all people (instead of 20+ individual files) and pull out data as needed for each graph.